# How detect if external website working or not?

Tags: php, http

How can I detect if external website working or not? I have thinked about HTTP ERROR MESSAGE. In general something as:

```
if ( <<something(url)>> != 200 ) {
  // website defined in url working (up)
} else {
  // website defined in url not working (down)
}
```

200 is code that define a success querying url. Just so understood reading here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CURL. The example is adapted from [cur_getinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

```
// Create a curl handle
$ch = curl_init('http://stackoverflow.com/');
//Return only headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
// Execute
curl_exec($ch);
// Check if any error occurred
if(!curl_errno($ch))
   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
// Close handle
curl_close($ch);

if ( isset($info) && $info['http_code'] == 200 )
  echo "Website is up!";
else 
  echo "Website is down.";
```

Comment: ok thanks, just a question, using this method in case of problem on the website, it take some latency time? I mean is possible that answer arrive later after 1 or more seconds?

Comment: Well, testing it on a site i know is down it took 2 minutes to give up. I don't know that it's as much about the method as it is how long your server is willing to wait to see if it gets a response.

Comment: Cleaned up the answer a bit more and made it so it incorporates the bit you were asking for.

Comment: Ok thanks, just a small problem yet. When url not exist php return this message: Notice: Undefined variable: info in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 23. How can i fix it ? Need set error_reporting to 0 or there is some solution better?

Comment: assuming that's the line where it checks the `http_code`, you can check if `$info` is set first before trying to compare against it. See modification above.